# Are One D&D Playtest rules suitable for normal play?

Tags: dnd-5e, one-dnd-playtest

There's an article (that's constantly updated) listing play tested rule changes in One D&D vs 5e.

https://www.dicebreaker.com/games/one-dandd/how-to/one-dnd-changes

Can I rely on these rules to improve my game, or are they still experimental?

Comment: Specifically: "game breaking" is a really vague term. Which ones are you considering trying, what have you and your group tried, what problems are you trying to fix/experiences are you trying to improve, and what pain points have you run into while playtesting these? For starters.

Comment: As nitsua says above, if you can provide some more information in your question about the problems you are currently finding and hoping for one D&D fixes for, that would be incredibly helpful to the community.

Comment: @NautArch Ironically you guys answered the question perfectly and torpedoed it to oblivion at the same time. What future me is going to scroll a -4 question? Anyway, I'm returning to "long time listener" because I cringe whenever the notification tray lights up, which makes the other sites unusable.

Answer (score 9):

## Playtest to find out

The most recent of these articles (as of writing) is Player's Handbook Playtest 5 and it states on page 1:

> This article is presented for playtesting and feedback. The options here are **experimental and in draft form**. They aren’t officially part of the game. Your feedback will help determine whether we adopt it as official.

> **Power Level.** The character options you read here might be more or less powerful than options in the 2014 Player’s Handbook. If a design survives playtesting, **we adjust its power to the desirable level before publication**. This means an option could be more or less powerful in its final form.

Options in this article are experimental drafts that haven't been adjusted for publication. The expectation is that there can be problems, and if so they should be reported as feedback. These articles certainly haven't received the same scrutiny that officially published material has, so it's possible you will encounter a game breaking issue while playtesting this article. Even more so if, instead of playtesting the article as a whole, you pluck random parts of it.

Ultimately these articles are for playtesting, not for playing.